# save_post affect creation and deletion

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, save-post, wp-update-post, customization

I wrote a little bit of code to update the post name and slug (of my cpt) when saving. This is working nice when I update a post.

I just noticed theses few lines are affecting the creation and deletion of posts.

When I click to delete a post, a message appears and says the post has been deleted but it's not. It's always on my dashboard.

When I create a new post, I also get a successful message but the post isn't created.

When I remove this code, the add and delete is working.. So I think this hook cause something wrong.

```
function rohs_update_title($post_ID){
    $post_type = get_post_type($post_ID);

    // If this isn't a 'rohs_menu' post, don't update it.
    if ( "rohs_menu" != $post_type ) return;

    $postAuthorId = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_ID ); // get the post author ID

    $userToGetData = 'user_'.$postAuthorId;
    $restaurantName = get_field( 'nom_restaurant', $userToGetData );
    $date = get_field('date');

    remove_action( 'save_post', 'rohs_update_title' );

    $menuName = 'Menu du '.$date.' chez '.$restaurantName;  
    wp_update_post( array( 'post_id' => $post_ID, 'post_title' => $menuName, 'post_name' => sanitize_title($menuName)) );

    add_action( 'save_post', 'rohs_update_title' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'rohs_update_title', 10, 3 );
```

get_field is form acf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are something wrong in your code, Here I edited what you tried,

```
function rohs_update_title($post_ID){

$post_type = get_post_type($post_ID);

// If this isn't a 'rohs_menu' post, don't update it.
if ( "rohs_menu" != $post_type ) return;

$postAuthorId = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_ID ); // get the post author ID

$userToGetData = 'user_'.$postAuthorId;
$restaurantName = get_field( 'nom_restaurant', $userToGetData );
$date = get_field('date');

remove_action( 'save_post', 'rohs_update_title' );

$menuName = 'Menu du '.$date.' chez '.$restaurantName;  
wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_ID, 'post_title' => $menuName ) );

add_action( 'save_post', 'rohs_update_title' );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'rohs_update_title', 10, 1 );
```

Now try this and let me know

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I changed 'post_id' => $post_ID to 'ID' => $post_ID.

It work's. I don't know where I found 'post_id' but that looks wrong.

You also changed 10, 3 to 10, 1. Does it change something ? Can you please explain

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I changed it, since there is no means to set 3 where you are using only one argument '$post_id'